# Why does getFile() in org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource throw an exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipart

First of all, please understand that sentences can be strange because I use a translator.

I tried to use the getFile() method of the resource object returned by getResource() in multipartFile while implementing the Image Upload feature, but it is configured to throw an exception. I wonder why it is like this.

I've read Java Doc, but I can't tell because it only says that I'm throwing an exception

Comment: Could you please provide the code related of your Multi-Upload component and the stacktrace? It's needed as part of how to ask questions and makes it better trackable in order to provide correct answers and not just guessing/ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to understand your problem and help you.

The method `getFile()` is declared as "throws an exception". It doesn't mean it will throw an exception in any case. It just means that it CAN throw an exception under certain circumstances. This will force you as a programmer to implement some error handling logic. Usually in form of a try/catch block.

In this particular case the file should be "physically" accessed for reading. In a rare case it is not accessible or even doesn't exist anymore - you will get an exception and should handle it.

That's it all about. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The *abstract class `AbsractResource`* overrided the method *getFile()* which was inherited from the *Interface `Resource`*.

The reason why **getFile()** method of *Interface `Resource`* throws exceptions is,

- If there is a failure in reading of the file or in case of general resolution/reading failures the method throws `IOException`.

The implementation class i.e *`AbsractResource`* also throws an exception

- If the resource is not available in the file system the method throws `FileNotFoundException` by giving "description " and this message " cannot be resolved to absolute file path".

> Note: While `IOException` is a part of the method signature whereas `FileNotFoundException` is thrown in the implementation of the method.

Hope this helps.